# Find the right polygon contains specific Point

Tags: mysql, gis

I have a expert situation beyond my knowledge.
I have a polygon table and column named geom, which is contains millions of polygon coords with polygon datatype. When i send lat,lang, I want to select right polygon contains these coords. I lookup so many answers and didnt find the right result. My db version is 5.6. I hope you experts will help on this problem.

Here is one the results from my column named geom,

```
'POLYGON((32.832677661456 39.604395901764,32.835512741784 39.604451520825,32.835457628151 39.604632934478,32.83542524568 39.604933725003,32.835590964324 39.605704952638,32.834519250891 39.605843434172,32.834339561944 39.605868865521,32.833763769865 39.605950014069,32.833486350914 39.606015654716,32.833173277993 39.606086197256,32.832114796112 39.606214593239,32.832301872536 39.605240473323,32.832677661456 39.604395901764))',0
```

I need to get this polygon When i searched  with this point 32.832677661456 39.604395901764

Regards

Comment: Can you give some example records from your polygon table, to be sure we understand how polygons are encoded in your MySql table?

Comment: A sqlfiddle will look something [Like This Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05b0b) but with a real one with a few rows. Create the left part. And post the url. Then we either do the right part and send it back as a url, or post it here, or both of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns a result:

```
select AsText(polygon.geom)
from   polygon
where  Contains(polygon.geom, 
           PointFromText('POINT(32.832677661456 39.604395901764)'));
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc7ac/1), which has two tables, `polygon` (with the one value you provided), and `location` with two records, one of which has the point you provided, and another one with a point outside the given polygon.

The fiddle SQL finds that the first point is within the polygon:

```
select AsText(polygon.geom), AsText(location.geom)
from   polygon, location
where  Contains(polygon.geom, location.geom);
```

Comment: You're welcome, in fact I learned a lot myself in answering your question.